# How to call jwt verification function from routes?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

**verify_jwt_token**

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('./env/config.json')

module.exports = function(req,res,next) {
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
    if (token) {
        console.log("----------------------------------------");
        console.log(token);
        console.log("----------------------------------------");

        console.log(config.jwt_secret);
        console.log("----------------------------------------");

    // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.jwt_secret, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) { //failed verification.
                return res.json({"error": true});
            }
            req.decoded = decoded;
            next(); //no error, proceed
        });
    } else {
        // forbidden without token
        return res.status(403).send({
            "error": true
        });
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
 var user  = require('../controller/user.controller.js');
 var token_verify = require('../../config/verify_jwt_token.js')

module.exports = function (app) {

app.route('/register_user').post(user.register);
app.route('/login').get(user.login);


app.route('/auth',token_verify).get(user.auth);


}
```

I want to call j w t verification function from this route.I don't want to call from the controller. app.route('/auth',token_verify).get(user.auth); Calling from this route
 Please help. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work-ish:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

function jwtVerify (req, res, next) {
  console.log('verifying token...')
  // logic
  next()
}

app
  .use(jwtVerify)
  .route('/example')
  .get((req, res) => res.json({ hello: 'World' }))

app.listen(3000)
```

The issue you will run into is that the middleware will execute for **every** route you define because the middleware is applied to the `app` instance. To fix this, you need to make use of the [Router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router). Quick dirty example below:

`app.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const securedRoutes = require('./secured-routes')

function jwtVerify (req, res, next) {
  console.log('verifying token...')
  // logic
  next()
}

app.use('/secured', jwtVerify, securedRoutes)

app.listen(3000)
```

`secured-routes.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'Hello from secured routes' }))

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as correct if it helped.

Comment: StackOverflow is not allowing me to mark. Because of reputation and badges.